# Show specific page when opening Account window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Following on from my previous Dynamics CRM question ([Show popup/alert if account has related entity records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027404/show-popup-alert-if-account-has-related-entity-records))

In the OnLoad event of the Account form, I want to set the window to open with a specific sub-navigation item loaded into the right-hand frame.

For example, by default, when you open the Account window, it loads the account details. Listed on the left are various related items. I have a custom related entity called Alert. If a specific criteria is met in my javascript, I want the Alert entity view to be loaded into the right-hand view instead of the Account details.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using `Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get("navItemName").setFocus();`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest three approaches

Approach 1
1. add a tab>section>subgrid to show that associated view
2. use form.onload javascript to show/hide that tab depending on criteria

Approach 2 (probably unsupported)
1. use form.onload javascript to .click() the navigation link [you can take the associated entity name in webresource function parameters to make this a generic library]

Approach 3
Have you considered [custom forms in CRM 2011](http://www.resultondemand.nl/support/blog/post/Microsoft-CRM-2011-Multiple-Forms-basics.aspx)?